# Javascript month year script, how to write to an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a javascript that just shows the date and time. It works and places the date and time at the top of the body. I just don't know how to get it to write inside a `<div id="time">`

This is the month/day script

```
function makeArray () {
    for (i = 0; i < makeArray.arguments.length; i++)
        this[i + 1] = makeArray.arguments[i];
    }

    var months = new makeArray('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
        'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var yy = date.getYear();
    var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;

    document.write(months[month] + " " + day + " " );
    //
```

Comment: $('#elementId').html('whatever you want');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = months[month] + " " + day + " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
document.write(months[month] + " " + day + " " );
```

With this:

```
$('#time').html( months[month] + " " + day + " " );
```

Or:

```
var dd = months[month] + " " + day + " ";
$('#time').html(dd);
```

---

Note that jQuery library must be loaded (usually in the `<head>` tags of your document), like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I tried yours it did not work, maybe I got something wrong, but the one by Lucky Soni did. But thanks for helping and sticking up for this beginner :-)

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia Hi Michael. Both my answer and Ginden's should have worked. Do you have jQuery loaded in the `<head>` tags of your document? See edits to my answer. (It doesn't matter to me who gets the points, I just want to make sure you learn correctly. *You can, however, upvote both Ginden's and my answers if you find that they work*).

Comment: Oh I was just trying to do javascript. Sorry about the tag, I put it in because Stackoverflow suggested it. I was really just trying to learn how to assign ID's in javascript and used this time script as an example. I started learning Jquery before Javascript and I figured I should know Javascript better.

Comment: Also I voted your answer up so you should get some points anyway for helping, thanks again!

Comment: you should see a surge in points, I just voted a bunch of your questions up :)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will look forward to helping you on future questions. That's how we all grow and develop as coders - "pushing one another up the ladder", so to speak. Best wishes.